# Select query on the MAP or JSON data set by using PartiQL contains in AWS

Tags: node.js, amazon-dynamodb, partiql

I would like to fetch results from AWS DynamoDB by using PartiQL. I am able to fetch the data for normal items. I am using this code -

```
const statement = `SELECT * FROM "dbname.int"  WHERE contains("item3", '{"accountName": 'val2'}')`;
const results = await db.executeStatement({Statement: statement}).promise();
```

DynamoDB structure - item1(String type) -> 'some value'
item1(Number type) -> 0
item3(MAP type) -> '{"accountName": "Dummy Name", "city": "Delhi", "info":{"info1": "info val"}'

I am looking for accountName value which contains 'Dummy' text.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM "dbname.int"  WHERE contains(item3.accountName, 'val2')
```